# iOS search a collection view faster

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

In my app, I am using a collection view with a searchable to let the user find people records stored in coredata.  I have the search setup to run as each character is entered.  Initially, this worked great, but now that I have a large set of data, the UI is lagging.  I am thinking I need to use another thread to do this, but I am an utter noob at multithreading.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController]performFetch:&error]) {
        abort();
    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Is there a way to do speed this up?

Edit:  I should have noted that the search string is feeding into he predicate on the fetch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I HAVE USE [THIS](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/10/02/dynamically-loading-new-rows-into-a-table.html) APPROACH FOR UITABLEVIEW FROM database and it worked like charm.
how you have implemented :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

can you show us code of height as well,

some code sample:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
 self.feed.counter = 50;

 totalcustomers = [cust getTotalCustomer:@"textSearch" searchText:searchtextString custType:YES employeeId:@"" custId:[module getCurrentOrderCustomerId]];

        self.currentSearchTitle = searchText;

        [cust setDatabasePath:DELEGATE.databasePath];

        self.feed.largeArray = (NSMutableArray *) [cust getSeachedCustomer:searchtextString custId:[module getCustomerId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]] action:@"textSearch"];

        self.availableCustomers = self.feed.largeArray;

        [self.allCustomerTable reloadData];

        NSLog(@"%d ",totalcustomers);
}
```

and load next 50 records on UITableviewScroll:

```
- (void)tableViewOverridedForScrollWithSearch:(UITableView *)tableView
                  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NSArray * newPosts;

            newPosts = [self.feed newRowsFrom:indexPath.row andAction:@"textSearch" andSearchString:self.currentSearchTitle];
            NSUInteger newCount = [newPosts count];



            if (newCount) {

                [self.availableCustomers addObjectsFromArray:newPosts];

                [self.allCustomerTable performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                return;
            }
        }

}
```

and get next 50

```
- (NSArray *)newRowsFrom:(NSUInteger)newItem andAction:(NSString *)action andSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{

NSLog(@"Counter 1 Print >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> %d", self.counter);

NSArray *result = [self newRowsFromDatabase:self.counter andAction:action andSearchString:searchString];

self.counter = self.counter + 50;
NSLog(@"Counter 2 Print >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> %d", self.counter);
return result;
```

}

hope it will help you
Thanks

Comment: I am not getting how this will speed up a search from a UISearchBar...

My cellForItemAtIndexPath is very standard.  Create a cell, get the entity object from the fetchedresultscontroller, set cell properties...  I don't have code for height...

Comment: if you see there are two things involved : 1.the search and 2.loareload data in collection. so as you stated that when there is less data , it works fine.so if a user types "a", just get first 50 data , update datasource and reload collectionview.now when user scroll then load next 50 data.and so on, i have implemented such functionality in my app in "search, index, scroll below" with a common engine which fetchs from data(search data/simple without search data, index data) base.i will show code snippet in a while

Answer (score 1):

Fetch All the results once and save them in an array. Then search from that array instead of fetching from core data every time the method is called.

Comment: Thanks.  I've never wired up a collection view or tableview to an array.  I'll look into it.